# Troubling definition of a cut vertex

Tags: graph-theory

So, I have perfectly fine intuition of a cut vertex $v$ of a graph $G$; that's the vertex for which stands that if I remove $v$ from $G$ I will get the graph $G-v$ for which the number of components of connectivity is now greater, that is, $\omega{(G-v)} > \omega{(G)}$ (very simillar to a the deinition of a cut edge).

Now, in our class, we defined a cut vertex in a more formal way. Before this, I maybe should mention that $G[E(H)]$ in our textbook represents the graph induced by the set of vertices $E(H)$ of some subgraph $H$ of $G$ ($H \subset G$).

Okay, now the definition:

*We say that $v$ is a cut vertex if $E(G)$ **can be** partioned in to the two subsets $E_1(G)$ and $E_2(G)$ such that $G[E_1] \cap G[E_2] = \{v\}$.* I "feel" that this should be equivalent to a "common sense" definition, but I don't understand this completely (visually).

If ${v}$ is a cut vertex, it does not have to have the cut edge, but the following partition can be done safely for arbitarely chosen cut vertex ${v}$. For example, set $E_1 = \{e_i \in G\}$ and $E_2 = \{e \in G, e \neq e_i \forall i \in I\}$ and then the intersection is indeed $\{v\}$. Let's say that $w$ is not-cut vertex in $G$. I have a hard time understanding the definition in this case or especially when such not-cut vertex $w$ has a loop  $l$ (then it seems that we can set $E_1 = \{l\}$, $E_2 = \{\text{the rest of E(G)}\}$ where $l$ is a loop of $w$, and we will then as a result get (if $w$ is not isolated, of course) $G[E_1]\cap[E_2]$ = {w}, but this clearly is not true).

Please provide me with visual, intuitive or some other "simple" answer to my problem because this is getting me very uncomfortable and I can't calm my mind. Thanks.

Comment: Your paragraph "I understand, though..." is rather confusing. This statement is false, there are counterexamples: *... if $v$ is a cut vertex it must have at least one cut edge $e'$...* Also, a $w$ appears without any explanation.

Comment: @LeeMosher, you're right. (can imagine a a graph $G$; "square" without bottom edge where each of 4 edges are connected. Here the external graph is connected so there is no cut edges in $G$. It's safe ti say that partition $E_1 = \{e | e \in G\}, E_2 = \{\text{the rest of E(G)}\}$ works. And yes, $w$ is defined as a not-cut vertex of $G$. I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

Not my favourite definition but I can try to explain.

As you have noticed this defnition does have problems wiht loops.
I don't know much about multigraphs so I will stick to a case of G being simple graph.
As such:

Draw a vertical line and place vertex x on that line.
Now place all other vertices either on left or right of that line but not on it.

Let's denote all vertices on the left L and on the right R.

In this scenario your definition is equivalent to saying:
"X is cut vertex iff I can find such an arrangment that G[L+x] is connected, G[R+x] is connected and no edge crosses the vertical line"

In a way this definition puts cut vertices in between connected components. Like a person in a doorway, not quite in not quite out.

Try this method to draw a graph with a cut vertex but no cut edges.

Also here's a proof if you want:

=>
Place x on the line, rest of G[E1] on the left and rest of G[E2] on the right. By definition of E1 and E2 as partition of E[G] no edge crosses the line.

<=
If there is such arrangment then we can denote E1 = E(G[L+x]) and E2=E(G[R+x]).
The intersection of of induced subgraphs for those two is only x.